# Error CREATEing SolrCore 'sitecore_core_index': non legacy mode coreNodeName missing

Tags: solr, sitecore

I am currently trying to setup Sitecore 9.1.0 rev. 001564 XP1 with my Solr v. 7.2.1 Cluster that consist of 3 Solr servers that are running Zookeeper v. 3.4.13.

The issue comes when I try to create cores using the `Install-SitecoreConfiguration` PowerShell command:

```
Install-SitecoreConfiguration -Path sitecore-solr.json -v
```

It gives an error suggesting that `coreNodeName` is missing. I have checked the *core.properties* files and the coreNodeNames are set correctly.

I have also checked the *solrconfig.xml* and `property.update.autoCreateFields` is set to false.

The error is shown below:

```
[--------------------------------------------------------------------------------- CreateCores [1] : ManageSolrCore ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------]
VERBOSE: Tells Solr to create the new cores.
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Requesting" on target "https://MYHOST:8983/solr".
[CreateCores [1]]:[Requesting] https://MYHOST:8983/solr
VERBOSE: GET https://MYHOST:8983/solr with 0-byte payload
VERBOSE: received 13377-byte response of content type text/html;charset=utf-8
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Invoke-ManageSolrCoreTask -Address https://MYHOST:8983/solr -Action Create" on target "https://MYHOST:8983/solr".
[CreateCores [1]]:[SolrCore] Performing Create on https://MYHOST:8983/solr

VERBOSE: Updating Solr: Uri => 'https://MYHOST:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=Create&name=sitecore_core_index&property.update.autoCreateFields=false&wt=json'
VERBOSE: GET https://MYHOST:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=Create&name=sitecore_core_index&property.update.autoCreateFields=false&wt=json with 0-byte payload
Install-SitecoreConfiguration : Error CREATEing SolrCore 'sitecore_core_index': non legacy mode coreNodeName missing {update.autoCreateFields=false}
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-SitecoreConfiguration -Path C:\Users\admin\Documents\ ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Install-SitecoreConfiguration

[TIME] 00:00:17
Invoke-ManageSolrCoreTask : Error CREATEing SolrCore 'sitecore_core_index': non legacy mode coreNodeName missing {update.autoCreateFields=false}
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SitecoreInstallFramework\2.0.0\Public\Install-SitecoreConfiguration.ps1:641 char:25
+                         & $entry.Task.Command @paramSet | Out-Default
+                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Invoke-ManageSolrCoreTask
```

I have also tried to just `curl` the request it's making, but that gives the same result:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> curl 'https://MYHOST:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=Create&name=sitecore_core_index&property.update.autoCreateFields=false&wt=json'
curl : { "responseHeader":{ "status":400, "QTime":9}, "error":{ "metadata":[ "error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException", "root-error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException"], "msg":"Er
ror CREATEing SolrCore 'sitecore_core_index': non legacy mode coreNodeName missing {update.autoCreateFields=false}", "code":400}}
At line:1 char:1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem has been solved. It seems like this only works when starting Solr without Cloud enabled. When I started Solr without cloud I could run the scripts without any issues. So I had to create my own collections for Solr Cloud in order to fix this.

Comment: hey, I also faced same issue, I ran this command `/opt/bitnami/zookeeper/bin/zkCli.sh -zkhost apachesolr-dev-zookeeper:2181 -cmd clusterprop -name legacyCloud -val true
` in my zookeeper pod and it threw error `Command not found: Command not found apachesolr-dev-zookeeper:2181` I have posted my issue here, I would be thankful If you could go through it once - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74306236/error-createing-solrcore-new-core-corenodename-missing