# Error CREATEing SolrCore 'new_core': coreNodeName missing

Tags: solr, apache-zookeeper, bitnami

I have hosted [Bitnami helm chart](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/main/bitnami/solr) for Apache Solr in our dev cluster and when I tried to create a new core it says ,

```
Error CREATEing SolrCore 'new_core': coreNodeName missing {schema=schema.xml, dataDir=data, config=solrconfig.xml}
```

[image]

So, from [official documentation](https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/upgrade-notes/major-changes-in-solr-7.html), [this](https://lists.apache.org/thread/rsvlgk9zvyhn95mhdxh15ccxpg1nn5yn) and [this](https://www.twblogs.net/a/5c850463bd9eee35cd69f120?lang=zh-cn) link, I came to know that I have to set `legacyCloud` true.

So, I have logged into my zookeeper pod, and when i ran the command

```
/opt/bitnami/zookeeper/bin/zkCli.sh -zkhost apachesolr-dev-zookeeper:2181 -cmd clusterprop -name legacyCloud -val true
```

It threw the following error,

I even tried replacing host with `localhost`/ `127.0.0.1` and it says command not found.

**After trying for 5 hours of various approaches, I am requesting for the help as in where I am doing it wrong.**

```
Connecting to localhost:2181
ZooKeeper -server host:port -client-configuration properties-file cmd args
        addWatch [-m mode] path # optional mode is one of [PERSISTENT, PERSISTENT_RECURSIVE] - default is PERSISTENT_RECURSIVE
        addauth scheme auth
        close 
        config [-c] [-w] [-s]
        connect host:port
        create [-s] [-e] [-c] [-t ttl] path [data] [acl]
        delete [-v version] path
        deleteall path [-b batch size]
        delquota [-n|-b|-N|-B] path
        get [-s] [-w] path
        getAcl [-s] path
        getAllChildrenNumber path
        getEphemerals path
        history 
        listquota path
        ls [-s] [-w] [-R] path
        printwatches on|off
        quit 
        reconfig [-s] [-v version] [[-file path] | [-members serverID=host:port1:port2;port3[,...]*]] | [-add serverId=host:port1:port2;port3[,...]]* [-remove serverId[,...]*]
        redo cmdno
        removewatches path [-c|-d|-a] [-l]
        set [-s] [-v version] path data
        setAcl [-s] [-v version] [-R] path acl
        setquota -n|-b|-N|-B val path
        stat [-w] path
        sync path
        version 
        whoami 
Command not found: Command not found apachesolr-dev-zookeeper:2181
2022-11-03 15:42:34,114 [myid:] - ERROR [main:o.a.z.u.ServiceUtils@42] - Exiting JVM with code 127
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do two things :

1. create the core from terminal/command-line.
2. you need to create the folder with the core name into {SOLR_PATH}/server/solr/ location and then need to add the conf files and create an empty data folder also, then it will work from solr admin.